# One of several file-append redirections of "python --version" is repeatably 'overlooked' by bash, but the others aren't

Tags: bash, debian, shell-script, io-redirection

**Why is `bash` consistently passing one, specific redirected output from `python --version` to the console rather than appending to file, while every other output is redirected properly?**

I am developing a Python package dependent on `numpy`, `scipy`, and `h5py`, and want to set things up so that I can automatically run my test suite on various combinations of the different versions of these dependencies (sort of a 'local CI' implementation).  I'm using `virtualenv` to create different folders for each combination of versions, all prefixed with `env`:

```
$ ls -1d env*

env-p3.3.6n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.3.1
env-p3.4.0n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.4.0
env-p3.4.4n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.3.1
env-p3.4.4n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.5.0
env-p3.5.1n1.11.0s0.12.0h2.6.0
env-p3.5.1n1.11.0s0.12.1h2.6.0
env-p3.5.1n1.11.0s0.13.0h2.6.0
```

For the most part, the following `testall` script is working great:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the filename
fname=testresults

# Overwrite the test result file with the date/time
date > $fname
echo -e "\n" >> $fname

# Pull all the env folders in the loop
for fld in $( ls -1 | grep -E "^env" )
do
   # Activate the virtualenv
   source $fld/bin/activate

   # Informative header
   echo "=============================" >> $fname
   echo $fld >> $fname
   python --version >> $fname
   pip freeze | grep -E '^(h5py|numpy|scipy)' >> $fname
   #echo -e "\n" >> $fname

   # Run the tests, dumped to file
   cd opan
   python tests.py --all 2>> ../$fname
   cd ..
   echo -e "\n" >> $fname

   # Leave the virtualenv
   deactivate

done
```

However, it's exhibiting a small, annoying misbehavior: the output from the first `python --version >> $fname` call is being sent to the console, while all others are redirected to file without a problem:

```
$./testall
Python 3.3.6
$ head -n28 testresults
Mon Jun 20 11:07:45 EDT 2016


=============================
env-p3.3.6n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.3.1
h5py==2.3.1                      <=== Python version is missing
numpy==1.7.0
scipy==0.12.0
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 315 tests in 3.254s

OK


=============================
env-p3.4.0n1.7.0s0.12.0h2.4.0
Python 3.4.0
h5py==2.4.0
numpy==1.7.0
scipy==0.12.0
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 315 tests in 3.230s

OK
```

What's going on here? How can I fix this?

Comment: By the way, it is generally a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`. It won't be an issue here as long as your file names are as you show and there is nothing else, but it would be both safer, more elegant and probably slightly faster if you just did `for fld in ./env*`

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the tip -- now that you point it out, globbing makes `ls` superfluous anywhere one cares only about the file/directory names, right?

Comment: Yes, but more than superfluous, [it's dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The rule of thumb is that of you're parsing `ls` to get a list of file names (as opposed to, say `ls -i` to get inodes) you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This looks a lot like you're reinventing [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @Wieland Very possible. I will now actually read up on `tox`.

Comment: @Wieland Looking at the `tox` dox, I don't see a way to specify versions of package dependencies (e.g., scipy==0.12.0), only versions of Python itself (and only up to 3.4 in the present version, looks like). Seems like I'd have to create a new tox.ini environment for each set of dependencies I wanted to test... not much of an effort savings over the above approach. `tox` I could push to CI, though, so that's an advantage there.

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend the `cd subdirectory; some_code; cd ..` construct. It's fragile and depends on `subdirectory` not being a symlink, etc. Unless you need to retain variables' values I'd suggest `( cd subdirectory; some_code )` instead, where the `(...)` subshell discards its context on exit (including its current directory).

Comment: Huh, if I'd've known it was going to be off-topic I'd've just deleted it. Is this `stderr`/`stdout` behavior dichotomy of Python not of interest to the Unix.SE community, then? Oops....

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the suggestion, good point.  And, thanks all for the impromptu code review.

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic. It describes a relevant difference in behaviour between `python` versions, and it's not a fault of the OP that caused the problem to manifest.

Comment: @roaima Looking over the question again, it might've been the "randomly" in the title. Will see if the edit prompts re-open.

Comment: Also, you should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$fld"` and `"$fname"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: @G-Man Bah, you're right, slipped my mind.

Comment: @hBy2Py: You can let tox create the list of environments for you by using [factors](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#generating-environments-conditional-settings)

Comment: @Wieland There it is. Cool! I wonder if I was looking at an old version of the docs or something, I never saw anything like that. Tox!

Answer (score 3):

**This is occurring because the output for v3.3.6 was going to `stderr`, not `stdout`.**

Apparently, prior to v3.4.0 the output from `python --version` is sent to `stderr`, whereas in v3.4.0 and later this output is sent to `stdout`.

Redirection of both `stdout` and `stderr` to the output file works just fine:

```
python --version >> $fname 2>&1
```